# Fire Javascript event on input attempt at max characters

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a text area with a max length of 500 characters. I would like a tooltip to show only when max characters has been reached and user attempts to input. My previous implementation was using `.keyup()`, but that of course fires on all keys.

Since `on.(input, function())` doesn't fire at max characters, I'm having trouble finding a solution around stackoverflow, google, jquery docs, etc. that suits my needs.

I'm just showing an animation for validation at max characters.  How can I get this to fire at input attempt at max characters?

```js
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var maxlength = parseInt($(this).attr('maxLength'));
  if (length >= maxlength) {
    var elem = $(this);
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").html("Max " + maxlength + " characters ").show();
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").stop(true, true);
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").fadeIn(0);
    $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").delay(1000).fadeOut(1300, function() {
      elem.removeClass("is-invalid");
    });
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea type="text" id="TestTextArea" class="form-control" rows="2" maxlength="25" required> </textarea>
    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
      Test tooltip
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you say: `.on('input')` *does not fire at max characters*, do you mean it fires at max-1 characters? in that case could you consider setting the max at 501?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keypress` only fires when you attempt to input something.

```js
$("textarea").keypress(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var maxlength = parseInt($(this).attr('maxLength'));
  if (length >= maxlength && window.getSelection() == "") {
    var elem = $(this);
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").html("Max " + maxlength + " characters ").show();
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").stop(true, true);
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").fadeIn(0);
    $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
    $(this).next(".invalid-tooltip").delay(1000).fadeOut(1300, function() {
      elem.removeClass("is-invalid");
    });
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea type="text" id="TestTextArea" class="form-control" rows="2" maxlength="25" required> </textarea>
    <div class="invalid-tooltip">
      Test tooltip
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ran into a use case here, so it's not perfect functionality but good enough for what I'm doing. If you select all at max length and start typing error will display on the first keypress.

Comment: @lloyd updated. Using `window.getSelection()` to check if user select any text.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just disable the textbox when length >= maxlength?

```
    $("#textarea").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```